# Regex that matches files in passed in folder

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of files:

`a/b/c
a/b/c.data
a/b/c/d
a/b/c/d.data`

When I pass in folder path `a/b/`, I want to return a list of strings of files in that folder. In this case, `a/b/c` and `a/b/c.data` should be returned. I have tried `(a\/b\/).+(?!\/)` but `String.matches(<regex>)` returns `true` for all for them.

PS: file name doesn't end with `/`.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? where is your code?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Would you please enhance it a little bit so that we understand it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Files.walk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-)

```
Files
  .walk(Paths.get("YOUR_PATH"))
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you want only the files then you could do this:

```
Files
   .walk(Paths.get("YOUR_PATH"))
   .map(Path::toFile)             // convert Paths to Files
   .filter(File::isFile)          // filter to remove directories
   .map(File::toString)           // convert files to Strings
   .collect(Collectors.toList()); // to return a list of Strings
```

Comment: @novo please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)